# IRC cannot login server irc.freenode.net

Tags: irc

I use Xchat Azure for using IRC.

but recently when I login irc.freenode.net server, I will get error, below:

```
Closing link: (~mark@102.139.205.20) [You must use TLS/SSL and authenticate via SASL to connect to freenode please visit https://irc.com/login/sso in order to create an account. SASL Configuration: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl - Webchat: https://webchat.freenode.net/]
 * Disconnected (Remote host closed socket).
```

I have checked this link(`https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl`) and tested the IRCCloud, but still not work,

please help me with this issue.

Comment: When was the last time you _did_ successfully log in to this server? Many things happened to freenode.net over the last month or two.

Comment: Would you please tell me what happened

Comment: It got bought, then it got destroyed, then it got restarted with completely different people running the show. All accounts and channels were wiped clean in June, so you actually cannot log in because your account no longer exists. Only the logo is still the same. See old posts [on news sites](https://www.reddit.com/r/irc/).